# JSON - replacement characters for Rest API query

Tags: json, api, rest

I'm trying to retrieve data from a WEB API rest server.

https://stat-xplore.dwp.gov.uk/webapi/online-help/Open-Data-API.html

Which stores the data in Cubes.

I understand the basics and am successfully retrieving data. However I want to use a Postcode, (ZIP Code) grouping dimension.
This dimension groups postcodes by their first 3 characters.  CF1, CF2 etc.

The schema has this as the definition for sending the request for this dimension.

["str:group:UC_Households:X_Geography+%28postcode%29"]

I'm assuming I'm meant to replace the end part with the Postcode group that I'm interested in and enclose the postcode group with some special characters.

So far I have tried

```
["str:group:UC_Households:X_Geography:CF1"]
["str:group:UC_Households:X_Geography:'CF1'"]
["str:group:UC_Households:X_Geography:#CF1#"]
["str:group:UC_Households:X_Geography:CF1%"]
["str:group:UC_Households:X_Geography#CF1#"]
["str:group:UC_Households:X_GeographyCF1"]
["str:group:UC_Households:X_Geography:CF1"]
```

the complete JSON is

```
{ "database" : "str:database:UC_Households",
    "measures" : [ "str:count:UC_Households:V_F_UC_HOUSEHOLDS" ],
  
    "dimensions" : [

 [ "str:field:UC_Households:V_F_UC_HOUSEHOLDS:HNFAMILY_TYPE" ],

["str:group:UC_Households:X_Geography:CF1"]

]
  }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Did you get any response? I'm also struggling with this

Answer (score 0):

**How to easily generate the query JSON for the Stat-Xplore API**

1. Log into https://stat-xplore.dwp.gov.uk
2. Open the data set and table you want
3. In the top-right hand corner, find the "Download Table" tool
4. In the drop-down box, select "Open Data API Query (.json) and click "Go"
5. This will download a JSON file with the parameters for the query that describes the table you're looking at in your web browser. An example is shown below:

```
{
  "database" : "str:database:UC_Monthly",
  "measures" : [ "str:count:UC_Monthly:V_F_UC_CASELOAD_FULL" ],
  "recodes" : {
    "str:field:UC_Monthly:F_UC_DATE:DATE_NAME" : {
      "map" : [ [ "str:value:UC_Monthly:F_UC_DATE:DATE_NAME:C_UC_DATE:202010" ] ],
      "total" : false
    },
    "str:field:UC_Monthly:V_F_UC_CASELOAD_FULL:EMPLOYMENT_CODE" : {
      "map" : [ [ "str:value:UC_Monthly:V_F_UC_CASELOAD_FULL:EMPLOYMENT_CODE:C_UC_EMPLOYMENT:0" ], [ "str:value:UC_Monthly:V_F_UC_CASELOAD_FULL:EMPLOYMENT_CODE:C_UC_EMPLOYMENT:1" ] ],
      "total" : true
    },
    "str:field:UC_Monthly:V_F_UC_CASELOAD_FULL:PARLC_CODE" : {
      "map" : [ [ "str:value:UC_Monthly:V_F_UC_CASELOAD_FULL:PARLC_CODE:V_C_MASTERGEOG11_PARLC_TO_REGION:E14000541" ], [ "str:value:UC_Monthly:V_F_UC_CASELOAD_FULL:PARLC_CODE:V_C_MASTERGEOG11_PARLC_TO_REGION:E14000542" ], [ "str:value:UC_Monthly:V_F_UC_CASELOAD_FULL:PARLC_CODE:V_C_MASTERGEOG11_PARLC_TO_REGION:W07000041" ] ],
      "total" : true
    }
  },
  "dimensions" : [ [ "str:field:UC_Monthly:V_F_UC_CASELOAD_FULL:PARLC_CODE" ], [ "str:field:UC_Monthly:F_UC_DATE:DATE_NAME" ], [ "str:field:UC_Monthly:V_F_UC_CASELOAD_FULL:EMPLOYMENT_CODE" ] ]
}
```

The [API table endpoint docs](https://stat-xplore.dwp.gov.uk/webapi/online-help/Open-Data-API-Table.html) give more info.

---

**An explanation for OP's issue**

I'm also attempting to use this API. (I happen to be using Python `requests` library.)

If I make a request to the `/v1/table` endpoint where one dimension is of type `GROUP` (rather than `FIELD`)

```
measures=["str:count:UC_Monthly:V_F_UC_CASELOAD_FULL"],
dimensions=[["str:field:UC_Monthly:F_UC_DATE:DATE_NAME"], 
  ["str:group:UC_Monthly:X_Geography+%28residence-based%29"]
]
```

then this error 422 is returned in the HTTP response:

```
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 422 Client Error: Unprocessable Entity for url: https://stat-xplore.dwp.gov.uk/webapi/rest/v1/table
```

This is the payload of the response, which describes the error in more detail:

```
{
  "message":"Unexpected schema component type 'group' for 'str:group:UC_Monthly:X_Geography+%28residence-based%29'. Expected one of type [field, valueset, udf].",
  "errorType":"UNEXPECTED_SCHEMA_COMPONENT_TYPE_EXCEPTION",
  "component" : "str:group:UC_Monthly:X_Geography+%28residence-based%29",
  "type" : "group",
  "expectedTypes" : [ "field", "valueset", "udf" ]
}
```

If I understand this correctly, it's not complaining about the formatting of the string, it's saying that only `FIELD`, `VALUESET` and `UDF` objects are expected.

If you look at the `schema` endpoint one can retrieve info about the possible groups, fields, etc.

```
{
  'id': 'str:group:UC_Monthly:X_Geography+%28postcode%29',
  'label': 'Geography (postcode)',
  'location': 'https://stat-xplore.dwp.gov.uk/webapi/rest/v1/schema/str:group:UC_Monthly:X_Geography+%2528postcode%2529',
  'type': 'GROUP'
}
```